# write regex for the string starting with digits and ending with $ and the total length of string is atleast 4

Tags: regex

I tried

```
/^[0-9](\w)*[$]{4,}$/
```

but it only accepts the string of having $$$$ at last.

Comment: Your number qualifier is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your requirements:

```
/^(?=.{4,})\d+\$$/
```

The positive lookahead assertions can help you with restricting the length of string

Answer (score 0):

You can start the match with a digit, then match 2 or more word characters and end the match with a dollar sign.

That way the pattern has to match at least 4 characters.

```
^[0-9]\w{2,}\$$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mX1REE/1)

If the whole string should be at least 4 characters, start with a digit and end with a dollar sign, you can use the dot to match any character.

```
^[0-9].{2,}\$$
```

Comment: I think it should be `^[0-9].{2,}\$$` or `^[0-9][\w\W]{2,}\$$`. There is no mentioning of alphanumeric in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I saw the `\w` in the pattern of the OP and used that to be repeated. If any character is allowed then you can use those patterns indeed.

Comment: I noticed recently that `\w`is considered a digit matching pattern by many users, so I am not sure OP did not try to match "digits" with `\w`.